# Usage of "run counter to"

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the usage of "run counter to" correct?

> They are large company. if you run counter to them directly, it will go ill with you.

Comment: I'd use *if you run against them* or if I wanted to be specific, for example, if we were talking about a campaign: *if you run a campaign against them*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This falls oddly on my ear. We ordinarily speak of 'running counter to' impersonal forces like principles or regulations or tendencies, not entities capable of volition and action like people or companies, which call for verbs like *oppose* or *defy* or *resist*.

*Directly* should be placed to modify *counter*, "run directly counter".

You might write

> They're a large company; if you run directly counter to their ambitions it will go ill with you.